# AWS - Network Load Balancer created via kubectl is missing SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

**I am using kubectl to create Network Load Balancer**. The Load Balancer is **created, but without the SSL certificate I selected** - which is weird because I supplied the correct Certificate ARN as I found it in the Certificate Manager. This is how my metadata in the kubectl yaml file look like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: {CERTIFICATE ARN}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-1-2017-01"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

Does anyone have an idea why is the Network load balancer created without the certificate? I am able to add the certificate by editing the NLB later and then everything works as expected - but the deployment through kubectl doesnt work.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved - I am using Kubernetes version 1.14 and this feature is supported only from 1.15. Explained here

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/73297